# Probabilities of different forecasts from linear regression

Tags: regression, probability, confidence-interval, forecasting, prediction-interval

Let's suppose for the sake of simplicity that we have the following linear regression:

```
Y=a+b*X
```

Where `Y` would be the sales of company "Ynapmoc" in period `t`, and `X` the sales of the company in period `t-1`. The purpose of this problem is to make a prediction of the company's sales in the next period, using its history of sales.

Once we have solved the equation and gotten our parameters `a`, `b` we can make a forecast of sales in the next period (if we of course know the previous period's sales).

What I am interested in doing is instead of getting one forecast for the next period, get three forecasts. Every forecast would have a "likelihood" of happening. For instance suppose we get the following for our regression above:

```
a=200
b=1.1
X=10,000
```

Based on those the prediction for `Y` would be 11,200. Would it be possible (e.g. with confidence intervals of the parameter) to get to something like:

```
Prediction 1 for Y: 9,000 - 20% chance of happening
Prediction 2 for Y: 11,200 - 50% chance of happening
Prediction 3 for Y: 13,000 - 30% chance of happening
```

Thanks a ton

Comment: The short answer is "yes."  Better answers will point out that your selected model is inappropriate for these data and this task for several reasons: it appears to concern a binary response ("chance of happening") and the data, evidently being a time series, are likely strongly correlated.  If you're concerned about getting reasonable predictions, then you ought to completely change your question (after doing some research in time series analysis, please). Otherwise, you ought to do something to make this question less abstract and hypothetical.

Comment: by less hypothetical, whuber means that you need the full answer of the regression model (R-square, standard deviation, number of points, forecast horizon, etc,...). In two words, you say the forecast is normally distributed with an average a+b*X and a standard deviation computed from the above parameters. Then you make the usual confidence interval estimation. But, first thing first, did you made a plot, and checked that a linear (= not curved) regression is acceptable.

Comment: Thanks to both. I still need to "create" the database, and I am starting to consider what the best approach would be (linear regression, power model, VAR, etc.). As my name suggests I am far from an experienced statistician yet. I will revert back to this once I have a more concrete example.